# Mathematical puzzle 001

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle

18 ~ 21 = 9

45 ~ 90 = 0

16 ~ 12 = 4

67 ~ 12 = ?

I tried to solve it by taking LCM of each number, square rooting them, adding each digit, multiplying them and many other ways. However, I couldn't solve this Mathematical puzzle. If you can solve, help me. Thanks.

Edit 1: possible answers are 12, 25, 32, 36 or 40.
Edit 2: source is Kuark publications, Yos questions.

Comment: Why are *12, 25, 32, 36 or 40* possible answers?

Comment: I have got it from a book and it has possible answers.

Comment: @garakchy please state the name of the book as a source in the question!

Comment: @garakchy This type of puzzle has an infinite number of solutions. I can find a polynomial that fits any of the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

25

1. Sum the digits of two given numbers, you get 13 and 3 for first one
2. Take the difference of sums i.e. 10
3. Divide by 2 i.e. 5
4. Now square it i.e. 25